# Getting error "This method must return a result of type java.lang.String"

Tags: java, return-value

Suppose that `file.txt` only contains "Hello". When I compile the Java code, it shows

> Error: This method must return a result of type java.lang.String in line5.

When I print in `readTxt` function, that works, it can show "Hello".
I already check the result is correctly String type, but it also shows compiler error. How can I make the return value to the main function?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.String;

public class ReadTxtFile {
public static String readTxt(String filePath) {

  try {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if(file.isFile() && file.exists()) {
      InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),     "utf-8");
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
      String lineTxt = null;
      lineTxt = br.readLine();
      //System.out.println(lineTxt);
      br.close();
      return lineTxt;
    } else {
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
  }

  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath = "C:/file.txt";
    String fileword = readTxt(filePath);
    System.out.println(fileword);
  }

}
```

Comment: what happens if `file.isFile() && file.exists()` is false?  Maybe change it to show `File does not exists`

Comment: Never catch exceptions without handle it. Do not catch the base class of all exceptions. Catch only checked exceptions

Comment: You do not return anything in case of an excception end in case you are trunning into else path

Answer (score 3):

You promised to return a String from your method, so you now have to do that. The only way around that promise is to throw an exception.

```
public static String readTxt(String filePath) { // Here you promise to return a String
  try {
    ...
    if(file.isFile() && file.exists()) {
      ...
      return lineTxt; // Here you return a String as promised
    } else {
      // Here you're missing either return or throw
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Here you're missing either return or throw
  }
}
```

This is fundamentally a design problem - what should your method do if it fails to read the file for some reason? Return a special string like "Error"? Return `null`? Fail and throw and exception? Something else?

Answer that to yourself and it will be clear to you how to fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several best practices you should follow that will prevent future error. I have tried to cover them. Not saying mine is the perfect one, but you will get the idea.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class StackOverFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String sText = getFileText("C:/file.txt");
            System.out.println("Text is: " + sText);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not Found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("@Error while reading text: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static String getFileText(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        File file = new File(filePath);
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String ls = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try{
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
                stringBuilder.append(ls);
            }
            reader.close();
        }finally {
            reader.close();
        }
        return new String(stringBuilder);
    }
}
```